# How do I grab the value of hidden field on gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is really frustrating right now.

I have this hidden field on gridview markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>  
  <asp:HiddenField ID="dhide" Value='<%# Eval("shipDates","{0:M/dd/yyyy}") %>' runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then on codebehind, I am trying to retrieve the value of dhide:

Sub cancelIt_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim objConnection As SqlConnection

```
Dim DLdates As HiddenField = DirectCast(GridView1.FindControl("dhide"), HiddenField)
Response.write (DLdates)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NamingContainer` of it is not the `GridView` but the `GridViewRow` where it sits.

So:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows 
    Dim dhide = DirectCast(row.FindControl("dhide"), HiddenField)
    Dim shipDates = Date.ParseExact(dhide.Value, "M/dd/yyyy", Nothing)
    ' ...
Next
```

Comment: thank you sir for your prompt response but I get an error that dhide is not declared.

Comment: @Kenny: Corrected VB.NET syntax since i have used a C# mix before.